# Can I whitelist all domains for Keycloak in the development environment?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

Let's say we have a lot of projects. Project1, Project2, etc. and let's say their local development domains are `example1.local` and `example2.local`, etc.

Now we have set up a Keycloak instance of our development machine, with a `Development` realm inside it, with an `AdminPanel` client in that realm, and we want to use it for all of our projects.

We can manually add `https://example1.local/*` and `https://example2.local/*` etc. to `valid redirect URLs` and `web origins`.

But this means that we need to add each and every project we have and we do many many projects per year.

We tried `https://*` but it did not let us login complaining about *invalid redirect_uri*.

Is it possible to whitelist every domain for Keycloak?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that. I suggest to check your configuration again. Something like this works perfectly for my scenario which is the same as yours. The only difference is that I created a dedicated client for my applications, but still it's single client for many dev environments:

**Valid Redirect URIs**: https://* or https://*.local

**Web Origin**: *

Don't put anything extra for `Web Origin`. Just the `*` but this is only needed for example if you want to use a swagger-ui hosted on somewhere else. It allows swagger from any domain ask for token from the Keycloak. If you don't put the *, due to CORS error, the swagger-ui or any tools like that would not be able to fetch token.

It's a minor thing, but worth mentioning that you put http**s**:// in the config, so the client app should also be accessed using http**s**. If someone type http by mistake, the same error would be returned.

Comment: Your answer did not work for me. But it triggered me to search more and I found [this](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/9278) discussion. And I used `*` for both **Valid Redirec URIs** and **Web Origin** and it worked. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

> We tried https://* but it did not let us login complaining about
> invalid redirect_uri.

Unless you are working in a testing environment, or you want to get hacked, **DO NOT DO THIS** in a production environment. From [OAuth 2.0 Security Best Current Practice](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics#section-4.1.1) you read an explanation of a an exploit based on this misconfiguration.

Therefore, you should make your registered redirect URIs as specific as feasible, and simply using a wildcard in a big no-no.

> But this means that we need to add each and every project we have and
> we do many many projects per year.

Wouldn't it be possible to automatize this via scripts or so? Get the project names and then call the Keycloak Admin API to add those redirectURIs to the client?!

Comment: Yeah we only want to do that for our development environment. And `*` did the trick.